# Strange thing in python: time speed depends on index in list when I open it

Tags: python-2.7

I'm using python 2.7 with spyder IDE.
I've written the code to open the two files for deep learning.

Below is the part of the code for simplicity.
The problem comes from the index in list.

If I write the code correctly as `idx=shuffle_range[batch_size*j+i]`,
speed decreases 6 times than writing the code as `idx=shuffle_range[j+i]`.
`idx=shuffle_range[j+i]` was written just for debugging.

I also changed it from range to `xrange`. But, it is not reason of the problem.

Is this a bug? How can I fix it? 
Please, help me!

Thank you.

```
import csv
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import time

data_num=72757
batch_size=64

shuffle_range=np.random.permutation(data_num)
nb_iter=data_num/batch_size

for j in range(nb_iter):
    start_time=time.time()
    for i in range(batch_size):       
        #idx=shuffle_range[j+i]       
        idx=shuffle_range[batch_size*j+i]
        #idx=60000+i        

        #data         
        img_file="datasets/train/data/depthFrame_%d.png"%idx             
        img=(Image.open(img_file))      
        img=np.asarray(img,dtype='float32')

        #label        

        csv_file=open("datasets/train/label128/label%d.txt"%(idx),'r')        
        csv_reader=csv.reader(csv_file)

        label_csv=[]
        for row in csv_reader:    
            label_csv.append(row)           
        csv_file.close()
        label_csv=np.asarray(label_csv,dtype='int')      

        csv_file.close()


    print time.time()-start_time
```

Answer (score 1):

When you index with `shuffle_range[j+i]`, you can get the same index value from multiple combinations of `i` and `j` values (consider index 1, which can be reached with `j=0` and `i=1` as well as `j=1` and `i=0`).  This overlapping of indexes between batches means that many of the data files will be opened repeatedly (up to `batch_size` times each), while many more are not opened at all. When you change the indexing to `shuffle_range[batch_size*j+i]`, you no longer get any overlap between the indices in different batches, and each file is opened exactly once.

Note that in both cases, the same total number of iterations of the inner loop will occur. But repeating the process with the same data may be faster for a variety of reasons. I suspect the biggest reason is disk caching. A file that has already been read may still be stored in memory by the OS when it's opened again later, so its content doesn't need to be read from the physical disk again. That can speed things up dramatically if the file reading takes a large part of your code's total run time.

You may be able to see evidence of this in your time printouts. I'd expect the first batch of each run to usually take about the same amount of time (regardless of which indexes you use). If you're using non-overlapping indexes, the later batches will take a similar amount of time. But if your batches do overlap, you'll find the later batches are much quicker than the first one.

Comment: This is helpful comment for this problem. In the training loop of my code, the required time to read the files is shorter than doing it during previous epoch. It may come from the reason that you said. Thank you very much.  I'd like to ask you one more thing. Is there a method to alleviate the problem? Actually, this is not really problem for now. Just I want to know more. Can I improve the time performance to read the files in my code?